# Postgis install failure, Could not find libpq

Tags: postgresql, postgis-installation

When i install postgis-3.2.1 with command ./configure, then error happen:

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvXD7.png)

But, libpq do exists in system.

[libpq.so location image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x16pF.png)

I'm confused!

Comment: You'll have to read `config.log`. Towards the end, you will see the error that made `configure` fail.

Comment: Do not use images for textual data, copy and paste the information as text into your question. More information needed 1) OS and version? 2) How was Postgres installed and from where? Add information as update to question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After I read `config.log`,  I found that I didn't install `redhat-rpm-config` package. Now, build success.